# Complex DELETE SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a SQL QUERY which will DELETE a record in the `album` table, only if the signed in client meets these requirements:

```
// Variables as a demonstration
const signedClientId = 1;
const albumIdToDelete = 2;
```

Requirements

1. The Client has an associated Album in the `clients_albums` table
2. ---- ***OR*** ----
3. The Album exists in the `domains_albums` table and the Client is the owner of the domain

I have 5 tables:

1. albums - id | name
2. clients - id | first_name | last_name
3. domains - id | owner (fk -> clients) | name
4. clients_albums - client (fk -> clients) | album (fk -> albums)
5. domains_albums - domain (fk -> domains) | album (fk -> albums)

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal - I added the solution to the question.

Comment: This is an english speaking site, so please use english only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
DELETE 
FROM albums
WHERE album_id IN 
(SELECT album_id 
 FROM clients_albums
 WHERE client_id = @CLIENTID)
OR
WHERE album_id IN
(SELECT album_id
 FROM domain_albums JOIN domains ON domain_albums.album = albums.id
 WHERE domains.owner = @CLIENTID)
```

`@CLIENTID` is a placeholder where you can pass in the client id in whichever query system you use.

Comment: Why JOIN and not LEFT JOIN?

Comment: JOIN: "Returns records that have matching values in both tables" vs
LEFT JOIN: "Return all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table".  You don't want ALL the records from left table now do you?